# Nodejs - What is the use of req.url parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(req.url);
  res.end();
}).listen(2020);
```

What is the use of req.url parameter? Will it be alright if I don't use it? Also, does passing a parameter in res.write(); produce the same result as passing a parameter in res.write();

Comment: This is a basic example of a server that returns the request url for any request made to it. Not using `req.url` is fine, you could instead call `res.write("hello world!");` Also, if you want to create a website using node as backend, I definitely recommend using express and pug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are building an web app which loads some data when user clicks to the "fetch posts" button, now what happens browser fires http request and load data from server.However if user opens browsers developer tool and navigates to the "Network" tab and click the "fetch post" button then there will be an entry for the Http call like :- **http://domain.tld/fetch-posts** .So if user copies your url in the an script an call it in loop for huge number like **10^9**,then your server would not be able to serve others and probably crashed or if it is at auto scaling then god may help you to pay cost.This issue can prevented without using captcha with help of **req.url** in **NodeJS**,to use this we can make a general route like http://domain.tld/invoke and send encrypted parameters for next route to be called and then replace that parameter with req.url at server like **req.url** = **req.body.path** and call **next()** using **ExpressJs**.So each time user sees network tab there is one kind of url i.e **http://domain.tld/invoke**